# Metric spaces and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors, curvature

Suppose that it is given that the Riemann curvature tensor in a metric space of dimension $d\geq2$ can be written as   $$R_{abcd}=k(x^a)(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$$ where $x^a$ is a vector in the space.

What condition can I impose on $d$ to guarantee that $k(x^a)$ is a constant? I have been told that such a condition exists.

Not knowing what to do, I computed the contractions of the curvature tensor and got 
$$R_{bd}=g^{ac}R_{abcd}=k(d-1)g_{bd}$$ and 
$$R=g^{bd}g^{ac}R_{abcd}=kd(d-1)$$
But it probably is of no use?

Comment: You use d twice, once as a dimension, once as a subscript. Which one do you mean in your problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is Schur's lemma. The statement is that in dimension at least 3, if the sectional curvature at each points does not depend on the tangent 2-plane taken (i.e. the sectional curvature only depends on the point), then the sectional curvature is constant.

Starting from
$$R_{ijkl}=k(x)(g_{ik}g_{jl}-g_{il}g_{jk}),$$
this can be seen by substituting this into the second Bianchi identity
$$\nabla_mR_{ijkl}+\nabla_iR_{jmkl}+\nabla_jR_{mikl}=0.$$
In particular you get
$$\nabla_mk (g_{ik}g_{jl}-g_{il}g_{jk})+\nabla_ik(g_{jk}g_{ml}-g_{jl}g_{mk})+\nabla_jk(g_{mk}g_{il}-g_{ml}g_{ik})=0.$$
Since the dimension is at least 3, we can take $i=k,$ $j=l$ and $m$ all distinct and this gives $\nabla_mk=0$, so that $k$ is constnat.